# What is the shortest way to get the last revision info of a file in cvs?

Tags: cvs

For getting check-in data about some file I use `cvs log filename` which prints long list of all revisions. Is threre a better way for getting only last check-in info (revision, data, user). I have seen `cvs log` options, the `-r` option want revision number. Is there a way of getting it without knowing the revision number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way, with `cvs log` to request just the last revision to a file, according to [this reference page](http://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#log).

`cvs log -N` excludes tag names, to shorten the output, and you could pipe it through `head -20`, for example, to reduce the volume of output:

```
cvs log -N filename | head -20
```

Depending in how clever you want to get - or how much time you want to spend on this -  you could do better, by using the fact that `cvs status` gives you the current version number of a file, e.g.

```
cvs -Q status  Readme.Overview.txt
===================================================================
File: Readme.Overview.txt       Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.7
   Repository revision: 1.7     /cvsroot/tortoisecvs/TortoiseCVS/Readme.Overview.txt,v
```

So you could write a script that extracts the `Working revision` value from that output, and then passes it to `cvs log -r`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by accident that using the -r option on its own (without giving a specific revision, range etc.) gives information about the latest revision only:

`cvs log -r filename`